# JAXB: Escaping RootElement

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jax-rs

I have a response class which actually returns the `Entity`object. Having `Response` and `Request` is part of the application specific architecture and can't get rid of it.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({Entity.class})
public class FindOneEntityResponse 
{
    @Override
    @JsonUnwrapped
    public Entity getValue() {
        return super.getValue();
    }

}
```

**Actual Response Xml:**

```
<Response>
  <Entity>
   <...></...>
   <...></...>
  <Entity>
</Response>
```

**Expected Response Xml:**

```
<Entity>
  <...></...>
  <...></...>
<Entity>
```

How can I get rid of class level root element?
I tried putting `@XmlTransient` with `@XmlRootElement` but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Is this Response within a soap response? If so, there isn't much you can do about.

Comment: Are you using JAXB directly, or through something like JAX-WS or JAX-RS?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan It is through JAX-RS.

Comment: Couldn't you just marshal the `Entity` object from the `Response` object, rather than the response object itself?